# Class does not exist exception if I don't provide full path to my class in Laravel validation extension

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.8 and attempting to set up a custom validation extension.

- I have created a class `GroupValidator` containing a `validate` function.
- I have created a `ValidationServiceProvider` with the following code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Classes\GroupValidator;

class ValidationExtensionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('valid_parent_id', 'GroupValidator@validate');
    }
}
```

When my validation triggers I get a `Class GroupValidator does not exist` exception. However if I specify the full path to my class in the extend function call like so:

```php
Validator::extend('valid_parent_id', 'App\Classes\GroupValidator@validate');
```

then everything works fine.

Is there some way I can set this up so that I don't have to include the full path to my class?

Comment: Why don't you want to include the full path, What is the problem with that? You can use the shortcut `GroupValidator::class . '@validate'` for a cleaner solution.

Comment: @olibiaz Simply because it's long-winded and if I add a lot of these extensions it would be nice if they were clean and readable. Thank you for that shortcut. I hadn't thought of that. Maybe we will use that.